# can we pass a ternary expression inside a component and send as a prop if condition is true or false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

can we pass a ternary expression inside a component and send as a prop if condition is true or false

```
<ExperienceList
   onUserToggle={this.onUserToggle} 
   jobs={this.state.jobs[this.state.value]}
   {
      this.state.jobs.length > 0 ? 
      allJobs={this.state.jobs} : null
   } 
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put the ternary expression inside :

```js
<ExperienceList 
  onUserToggle={this.onUserToggle} 
  jobs={this.state.jobs[this.state.value]}
  allJobs={this.state.jobs.length > 0 ? this.state.jobs : null}
/>
```